# Wordpress get_the_post_thumbnail only works for current post ID

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on creating a 'Related Articles' feature on my Wordpress site. It uses custom fields where the post author can paste links to related posts that will be displayed at the bottom of the current post. I want to display a thumbnail and a link for each related post.

Problem: `get_the_post_thumbnail` only works when I provide the ID for the current post. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here? Here's the code I'm using to generate a related post. I've confirmed that $url, $id, and $title all output as expected.

```
    <?php $url = get_field('url_01'); ?>
    <?php $id = url_to_postid($url); ?>
    <?php $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'yarpp-thumbnail'); ?>
    <?php $title = get_the_title($id); ?>

    <?php echo $thumb ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
```

Comment: I don't really see the issue here, if you don't give an ID it will get the one from the current post in the loop, that's a normal behaviour. Maybe share the loop part of your code?

Comment: But I *am* giving it an ID, and instead of returning the thumbnail it returns nothing.

Comment: The ID I'm passing it is independent of the loop.

Comment: Ok I got misleaded by _get_the_post_thumbnail only works when I provide the ID for the current post_, thought it was working as intended. Did you checked that `url_to_postid` returns the right ID?

Comment: It turns out that even though the code didn't work in my sandbox, it works fine in QA. So I have no idea what was causing the error, but it must be some sort of environment issue.

Comment: Maybe there is something different in database in your sandbox environment. I would check on the `url_01` values in the post meta table, and maybe compare the `$id` values on both environment.